# The differences between if else and #if #else #endif

Tags: c++, c, macrodef

I am confused between the `if`/`else` and `#if`/`#else`/`#endif` constructs.

1. What are the differences between them?
2. In which specific situations should I use each of them?

Comment: No, they don't have the same logic functionality, nor do they seem to have that.

Comment: Why don't you try replacing `if` with `#if` and see if it works properly.

Comment: A macro driven behaviour happens at different time than syntax. No they don't have same logic functionality.

Comment: See https://docs.freebsd.org/info/cpp/cpp.pdf , http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I am confused about the if/else and #if/#else/#endif. It seems that
>   they have the same logic functionality.
>
> Can I ask what's the differences between them?

`#if`, `#else` and `#endif` belong to preprocessing. They are **not executed** but are instructions for textual replacement. You can think of them as a kind of automatic "search & replace" feature you'd usually find in a text editor.

`if` and `else` are run-time constructs. You can think of them as being executed while the program runs.

Let's say you have this program:

```
#include <iostream>

#define VALUE 1

int main()
{
#if VALUE == 1
    std::cout << "one\n";
#else
    std::cout << "not one\n";
#endif
}
```

When you tell your compiler to compile this program, the preprocessor will make a textual replacement before the "real" C++ code is actually compiled. It will be as if the program was:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "one\n";
}
```

Now, technically you could use an `if` here:

```
#include <iostream>

#define VALUE 1

int main()
{
    if (VALUE == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "one\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "not one\n";
    }
}
```

But in C++ you **don't use `#define` for constants**. You'd instead have something like:

```
#include <iostream>

int const value = 1;

int main()
{
    if (value == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "one\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "not one\n";
    }
}
```

Perhaps the value is only known while the program executes, e.g. via user input. Then you obviously cannot use `#if`, which only works before the program runs. You must use `if`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int value;
    std::cin >> value; // gross simplification here

    if (value == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "one\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "not one\n";
    }
}

What kind of specific situations for me to choose each of them?
```

A good guideline for a beginner would be: Use `#if` (or actually: `#ifndef`) only for [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). Consider further uses of `#if` when you encounter problems that can only be solved by the preprocessor.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I am reading the source code of opencv, then I find there are lot marco definitions in the head files. Is it means those marco definitions well tell preprocessor which source files to compile?

Comment: @za17: without knowing OpenCV, I'd say those are either include guards (i.e. they prevent multiple processing of the same header file) or they enable special treatment for different compilers.

Answer (score 12):

`if(...)` and `else(...)` conditions are evaluated at runtime. `#if`, `#else` are evaluated before compile time by the preprocessor.

Comment: even before compile time ;)

Answer (score 6):

> Can I ask what's the differences between them?

`#if` `#else` and `#endif` are instructions to the compiler, to only compile the code between them, if a compilation level condition (like a macro being defined or having a certain value) is satisfied.

`if` and `else` are parts of the compiled algorithm.

> What kind of specific situations for me to choose each of them?

The pre-compilation conditions are used to disable parts of the code, in situations where they make no sense (like calls to Windows-specific APIs, when compiling under Linux). They are key to developing cross-platform code (for example).